# Recurrence relation problem with $a_{n-1}=2a_n+4^n$ for $n\geqslant 0$, and $a_1=3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

I have the given recurrence relation

[image]

So far I've got

[image]

What should I do next?

Can I just use generating function in general?

Comment: Is it $a_{n+1}=2a_n+4^n$?

Comment: If you did not make mistakes with writing your recurrence relation (as Robert Z pointed out above), then perhaps you should do this instead: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,a_{n-1}\,x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,(2\,a_n+4^n)\,x^n\,.$$  However, if Robert Z is right, then just correct the indices in your original attempt.

Comment: in my task, the question is like that.than thats question is undefined right ? expect n is >= 1 or its a_n+1 not a_n-1 .. am i right ?

Comment: You can "LaTeXify" your text with `$   $`.  For example, `$a_{n+1}$` produces $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: ok.. thanks.. :D