# solve recurrence system

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

Solve recurrencerelation system

$$(1) a_1 = b_1 = c_1 = 1 $$
$$(2) a_{n-1} = a_n + b_n + c_n, n  \ge 1 $$
$$(3) b_{n+1} = 4^n - c_n, n  \ge 1 $$
$$(4) c_{n+1} = 4^n - b_n, n  \ge 1 $$

Using generating function, at the end i got
$$B(x) = C(x) = \frac{3x^2 - 4x^3}{(1-4x) (1+x)} =  \frac{1/10}{(1-4x)}+ \frac{7/5}{(1+x)} $$

$$A(x) = \frac{B(x) + C(x) - 3}{x-1} = \frac{2(\frac{1/10}{(1-4x)}+ \frac{7/5}{(1+x)} - 3)}{x-1} $$

What should i do next? since we know that x-1 it can't be changed into generating function..

Comment: For $(2)$, did you mean $a_{n\color{red}+1}$?

Comment: Your generating functions aren’t right: what you have for $B(x)$ yields $b_1=-1,b_2=3,b_3=5,b_4=27$ instead of $1,3,13,51$, assuming that in $(2)$ you meant $a_{n+1}$ on the left.

Comment: in my task, its written $$a n−1 $

Comment: @FaqihahNurZahirahM: It is likely that $a_{n-1}$ is an error.

Comment: $a_{n-1}$ versus  $a_{n+1}$. Another typo? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651719/recurrence-relation-problem-with-a-n-1-2a-n4n-for-n-geqslant-0-and-a-1/

Comment: Write all as partial fractions. You can (almost) read off coefficients of the result.

Comment: Remember $(1 - \alpha x)^{-1} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \alpha^k x^k$

Answer (score 1):

Define generating functions $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n$ and similarly $B(z), C(z)$. (the "$n + 1$" makes it overall more pleasant to work with by starting sums at 0). Shift recurrences by one (I believe it should be $a_{n + 1} = a_n  + b_n + c_n$), multiply by $z^n$:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
     &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
          + \sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n + 1} z^n
          + \sum_{n \ge 0} c_{n + 1} z^n \\
   \sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n + 2} z^n
     &= 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} 4^n z^n\sum_{n \ge 0}
          - c_{n + 1} z^n \\
   \sum_{n \ge 0} c_{n + 2} z^n
     &= 4 \sum_{n \ge 0} 4^n z^n\sum_{n \ge 0}
          - b_{n + 1} z^n
\end{align*}$

Recognize sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{A(z) - a_1}{z}
    &= A(z) + B(z) + C(z) \\
  \frac{B(z) - b_1}{z}
    &= \frac{4}{1 - 4 z} - C(z) \\
  \frac{B(z) - b_1}{z}
    &= \frac{4}{1 - 4 z} - B(z)
\end{align*}$

Use initial values, solve for the generating functions, as partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
   A(z)
     &= \frac{1 - z - 4 z^2}{(1 - z) (1 + z) (1 - 4 z)} \\
     &= \frac{2}{3 (1 - z)}
          - \frac{5}{1 + z}
          + \frac{8}{15(1 - 4 z)} \\
   B(z)
     &= C(z) \\
     &= \frac{1}{(1 + z) (1 - 4 z)} \\
     &= \frac{5}{1 + z} + \frac{4}{5 (1 - 4 z)}
\end{align*}$

Everything in sight is just geometric series:

$\begin{align*}
   a_n
     &= [z^{n - 1}] A(z) \\
     &= \frac{2}{3} \cdot 1^{n - 1}
         - 5 \cdot (-1)^{n - 1}
         + \frac{8}{15} \cdot 4^{n - 1} \\
     &= \frac{2}{3} + 5 \cdot (-1)^n + \frac{2}{15} \cdot 4^n \\
   b_n
     &= c_n \\
     &= [z^{n - 1}] B(z) \\
     &= \frac{1}{5} \cdot 1^{n - 1}
           + \frac{4}{5} \cdot 4^{n - 1} \\
     &= \frac{4^n - (-1)^n}{5} 
\end{align*}$

Comment: Thank you very much^^